# Set<Tuple> not properly adding values

Tags: java, google-app-engine, redis

I'm working on a open source Redis-like Memcache API: http://bit.ly/XVfpRX

Can anyone help me analyze why this code is getting a wrong value for the `String field`  and`String value` variable:

```
public Long hset(String key, String field, String value) {
    System.out.println("HSET key="+key+" field=" + field + " value="+value);
    try {
        boolean exist = exists(key);
        if(exist){
            Set<Tuple<String,String>> hash = (Set<Tuple<String,String>>) memget(key);
            Iterator<Tuple<String, String>> it = hash.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()){
                Tuple<String, String> t = it.next();
                if (t.getFirst().equals(field)){
                    System.out.println("HSET Removing field=" + t.getFirst() + " value="+t.getSecond());
                    hash.remove(t);
                    hash.add(new Tuple<String, String>(field, value));
                }
            }
            memset(key, hash);
            return 0L;
        } else {
            Set<Tuple<String,String>> hash = new HashSet<Tuple<String,String>>();
            System.out.println("Adding new tuple key="+key+" field=" + field + " value="+value);
            hash.add(new Tuple<String, String>(field, value));
            memset(key, hash);  
            return 1L;
        }
    } catch(Exception e) { //  ClassCastException and NPE
        // What to do when CCE is encountered?
        Set<Tuple<String,String>> hash = new HashSet<Tuple<String,String>>();
        hash.add(new Tuple<String, String>(field, value));
        memset(key, hash);              
    } 
    return 1L;
}
```

Here is the test logs:

```
Start hset tests
HSET key=null field=null value=null
Adding new tuple key=null field=null value=null
MEMSET key=null value=[Tuple [first=null, second=null]]
HSET key=foo field=foo value=bar
Adding new tuple key=foo field=foo value=bar
MEMSET key=foo value=[Tuple [first=foo, second=bar]]
HSET key=foo field=bar value=foobar
MEMSET key=foo value=[Tuple [first=foo, second=bar]]
HSET key=user:1 field=uname value=foo
Adding new tuple key=user:1 field=uname value=foo
MEMSET key=user:1 value=[Tuple [first=uname, second=foo]]
HSET key=user:1 field=fname value=Bar
MEMSET key=user:1 value=[Tuple [first=uname, second=foo]]
HSET key=user:1 field=uname value=bar
HSET Removing field=uname value=foo
MEMSET key=user:1 value=[Tuple [first=uname, second=bar]]
```

And there is the actual JUnit test:

```
@Test
public void testHset() {
    System.out.println("Start hset tests");
    Long ret = lingo.hset(key, null, value);
    assertEquals(1L, ret.longValue());
    ret = lingo.hset("foo", "foo", "bar");
    assertEquals(1L, ret.longValue());
    ret = lingo.hset("foo", "bar", "foobar");
    assertEquals(0L, ret.longValue());

    ret = lingo.hset("user:1", "uname", "foo");
    assertEquals(1L, ret.longValue());
    ret = lingo.hset("user:1", "fname", "Bar");
    assertEquals(0L, ret.longValue());
    ret = lingo.hset("user:1", "uname", "bar");
    assertEquals(0L, ret.longValue());

    String username = lingo.hget("user:1", "uname");
    String firstname = lingo.hget("user:1", "fname");
    assertEquals("bar", username);
    assertEquals("Bar", firstname);
    System.out.println("End hset tests");
}
```

The problem area is this:

```
HSET key=foo field=bar value=foobar
MEMSET key=foo value=[Tuple [first=foo, second=bar]]
```

and this:

```
HSET key=user:1 field=fname value=Bar
MEMSET key=user:1 value=[Tuple [first=uname, second=foo]]
```

The field and value being propagated to memset (which is a key-value wrapper method for GAE memcache put) is wrong.

[The Tuple code can be found here](http://grepcode.com/file_/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.jasig.portal/uportal-war/4.0.9.1/org/jasig/portal/utils/Tuple.java/?v=source).

**Update (Added hget method):**

```
public String hget(String key, String field) {
    try {
        boolean exist = exists(key);
        if(exist){
            Set<Tuple<String,String>> hash = (Set<Tuple<String,String>>) memget(key);
            Iterator<Tuple<String, String>> it = hash.iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()){
                Tuple<String, String> t = it.next();
                if (t.getFirst().equals(field)){
                    return t.getSecond();
                }
            }
        } 
    } catch(Exception e) { //  ClassCastException and NPE
        // What to do when CCE is encountered?
    } 
    return "nil";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you write that `Tuple` class?

My first thought would be that you didn't override `equals` and `hashCode` correctly.  Joshua Bloch's [Effective Java](http://www.scribd.com/doc/36454091/Effective-Java-Chapter3) tells you how.

Comment: Nope, I just took that from the Jasig Portal code: http://grepcode.com/file_/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.jasig.portal/uportal-war/4.0.9.1/org/jasig/portal/utils/Tuple.java/?v=source

Comment: I am able to get back a Set<Tuple> hash that was serialized into the Memcache in my hget/memget method... so I really find this confusing

Comment: I mean for example this pass: assertEquals("bar", username);

Comment: No.  If you create two Tuples with identical values, can you add both to the Set?  You should not be able to, right?